# Aparecer um loading enquanto lê o carregamento do conteúdo JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>

<script>
      var qnt_result_pg = 20;
      var busca = "";
        var pagina = 1;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                listar_usuario(pagina, qnt_result_pg, busca);
            });
            function listar_usuario(pagina, qnt_result_pg, busca){
      var dados = {
                    pagina: pagina,
          busca: busca,
                    qnt_result_pg: qnt_result_pg
                }
                $.post('<?php echo $caminhoAbsoluto; ?>/listar-pagamentos-pendentes.php', dados , function(retorna){
                    $("#conteudo").html(retorna);
                });
            }
</script>
```

Ele me retorna a listagem dos usuários cadastrados na minha página, porém no banco tem mais de 7 mil cadastros e mesmo ter colocado uma paginação, ele demora alguns segundos para abrir. Como eu posso fazer para que apareça um loading enquanto o conteúdo não é carregado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode colocar uma imagem ou um elemento feito com CSS para aparecer enquanto os dados são carregados, após serem carregados basta ocultar o elemento da página.

No JavaScript você terá que colocar o *callback* `done()` que é executado quando a função conclui suas ações ficando: `$.post(// seu codigo).done(//acao após concluir post)`.

Nesse link tem a documentação do jQuery [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) que tem exemplos com `done()`.

Segue um código de exemplo pegando dados em JSON.

```js
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      $(".monark").append("<tr>"+
      "<td>"+val.id+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+val.nm+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+val.cty+"</td>"+      
      "<td>"+val.hse+"</td>"+      
      "<td>"+val.yrs+"</td>"+
      "</tr>");
    });
  }).done(function(){
    $(".outer").hide("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
  text-align: center;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 16px solid blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="monark"></table>
```

Comment: Obrigado Laércio. Um Feliz Natal para todos vocês!

Comment: Pra você também amigo. Um abraço!